# How to create a macro for a customized frame in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, macros, titles

I'm looking for a way to create a macro like `\chapterFrame{Title of the chapter}`which adds a new slide customized as I want.

As an (ugly) example, here is what it could look like.[image]

I tried the following macro, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[width=1.8cm]{Berkeley}
\newcommand\chapterFrame[1]{
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{block}{}
    \begin{center}
      \Huge Chapter 3 %add a counter

      \Large The title of the chapter
    \end{center}
  \end{block}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\chapterFrame{Title of the chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly what you want but... I guess that you can improve it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[width=1.8cm]{Berkeley}

\newenvironment{chapterFrame}[1]{%
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{block}{}\centering
      {\Huge Chapter \thesection}\par\medskip
      {\Large #1}
\end{block}
      \vfill\tableofcontents
}{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{chapterFrame}
{Title here}
\end{chapterFrame}

\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}{title}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{chapterFrame}
{content...}
\end{chapterFrame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why use `\thesection` to number the chapters? Isn't this problematic if you are also using sectioning?

Comment: Well the problem is the blank slate on the left, due to the side bar on normal slides. That's why I used the code `\makeatletter\setlength{\hoffset}{-.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}\makeatother` but it also seems to be the origin of the problem with my macro.

Comment: @cfr, it is just an example. Since the OP is using only `\section{}` I used that. But it is completely randomly.

Comment: @BonyHoax, I can not fix it. Sorry. I tried but that left bar is stronger then my code... lol