# Can we make a macro for \begin{frame}[t]\end{frame}?

Tags: beamer, luatex

I find myself using `\begin{frame}[t]\end{frame}` all the time. All my attempts to create a macro for it have failed. Is there a way?

Comment: Welcome. No, there isn't. Why would you obfuscate your code?

Comment: Actually, I meant it this way \end{fra Sorry.me}\begin{frame}[t].

Comment: If `\begin{frame}[t]\end{frame}` is too much for you to type, just set one of the editor's shortcuts to insert it for you, most of the editors I know of can do this.

Comment: This has been asked like a million times and it is not only answered on this site but also in the official documentation.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422868/creating-a-beginframefragile-macro

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156242/how-to-create-a-macro-for-a-customized-frame-in-beamer

Comment: If you want to set `t` for all frames, use `\documentclass[t]{beamer}` (see `beamer` manual, sec. 8.1). If you prefer command to environment, use `\frame{<contents of frame env>}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not into the underlying LaTeX mechanics and would like to seek for a *simplistic* way, you can just save your command into a file (e.g. `cmd.tex`) and declare a macro to `\input` it.

**cmd.tex**

```
\begin{frame}[t]\end{frame}
```

**main document**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\newframe}{\input{cmd.tex}}

\newframe
\newframe
\newframe
\newframe

\end{document}
```

### Edit: making use of files

As other answers have pointed out, there is no easy way of defining a macro as `\end{frame}\begin{frame}[t]`, because of LaTeX's parsing mechanism. The (only) way to escape from this dilemma is to make use of *files*, as I have pointed out before. To support what you want, we can design a (crazy) workaround:

1. Save your TeX source code to `file1`.
2. Suppose the macro your designed is `\framesep`. We read `file1` line by line and replace `\framesep` to `\end{frame}\begin{frame}[t]`. The result is saved as `file2`.
3. Read `file2`.

The code is shown as below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.myverb1}
\begin{frame}[t]
frame1
\framesep
frame2
\framesep
frame3
\end{frame}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% replace this regex...
\str_new:N \l_framesep_str 
\str_set:Nn \l_framesep_str {\\framesep}
% to...
\str_new:N \l_framecmd_str 
\str_set:Nn \l_framecmd_str  {\\end{frame}\\begin{frame}[t]}

\ior_new:N \l_infile_ior
\ior_open:Nn \l_infile_ior {\jobname.myverb1}
\iow_new:N \l_outfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \l_outfile_iow {\jobname.myverb2}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN {ooN}

\ior_str_map_variable:NNn \l_infile_ior \l_tmpa_str {
    \regex_replace_all:ooN {\l_framesep_str} {\l_framecmd_str} \l_tmpa_str
    \iow_now:Nx \l_outfile_iow {\l_tmpa_str}
}

\ior_close:N \l_infile_ior
\iow_close:N \l_outfile_iow

\ExplSyntaxOff

\input{\jobname.myverb2}

\end{document}
```

Note that this can also be done by calling a pre-processor before compiling your TeX source. For example, you can have a Python script doing the replacement first and then calling `latex`.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. Now, I try \end{frame}\begin{frame}[t] ad it does not work! I get ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \endframe ->\egroup \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame} l.1 \end{frame} \begin{frame}[t] Thank you again! latexatha –

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to substitute the combination

```latex
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
```

with, say

```
\breakframe
```

then the answer is *no, you can't*.

As `beamer` is implememented, it needs to absorb the complete frame code before processing it for making overlays and all other things. So LaTeX needs to see an *explicit* `\end{frame}` not buried into a macro. After processing `\begin{frame}` it looks forward until it finds `\end{frame}` doing *no* macro expansion, but simply absorbing tokens as it goes.

Yes, one might think to set up the presentation like

```latex
\startframes
...
\breakframe
...
\breakframe
...
\breakframe
\stopframes
```

but, unless you're wanting to absorb the whole presentation in one big swoop, the final part should be something as described above.

Is this so different from

```latex
\begin{frame}[t]
...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
...
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
...
\end{frame}
```

to go into the burden of rewriting code already working?

A good text editor can spare you the typing and produce

```latex
\begin{frame}[t]

\end{frame}
```

with the pression of a couple of keys, also placing the cursor in the blank space.